# Knockout Multiple Template Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have created a two template design for knockout template binding; one is `receiverTemplate` and  the other is `senderTemplate` for messaging and trying to bind with a `ul` tag via a `foreach` loop.

Here is my code in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwbxexeu/1/

It is giving me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to display a template on basis of a condition?

For e.g. if receiver is true display **receiverTemplate** else display **senderTemplate**.

Here is the code:

My viewmodel:

```
var viewModel = {
    messages: ko.observableArray([{
        received: true,
        name: 'Rohit Kesharwani',
        msgdate: '12 mins ago',
        msg: 'Hello User! How can I assist you?'
    },
    {
        received: false,
        name: 'Rahul Singh',
        msgdate: '11 mins ago',
        msg: 'I want to create a website using asp.net. Please assist me.'
    }])
}
```

Knockout Template:

a) Receiver Template

```
<script type="text/html" id="receiverTemplate">
       <li class="left clearfix">
          <span class="chat-img pull-left">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50/55C1E7/fff&amp;text=U" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
           </span>
           <div class="chat-body clearfix">
               <div class="header">
                 <strong class="primary-font" data-bind="text: name"></strong>
                 <small class="pull-right text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" data-bind="text: msgdate"></span></small>
               </div>
               <p data-bind="text: msg"></p>
            </div>
       </li>
 </script>
```

b) Sender Template

```
<script type="text/html" id="senderTemplate">
       <li class="right clearfix">
             <span class="chat-img pull-right">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/FA6F57/fff&amp;text=ME" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
              </span>
              <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                  <div class="header">
                     <small class=" text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" data-bind="text: msgdate"></span></small>
                     <strong class="pull-right primary-font" data-bind="text: name"></strong>
                  </div>
                  <p data-bind="text: msg"></p>
              </div>
        </li>
</script>
```

Template binding with HTML:

```
<ul class="chat" data-bind="template: { name: 'receiverTemplate', foreach: messages }" id="message-panel" style="display: none;">
</ul>
```

Applying binding:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

Comment: after unhiding the content, I don't see any errors: http://jsfiddle.net/nwbxexeu/2/ can you add details on how to reproduce the issue and describe why the content is hidden?

Comment: There's a reason you got an error that you needed to show code *in* the question. Please show us your code on Stack Overflow, possibly leaving the fiddle link as support. Let us know what you've researched/debugged so far. In addition it may help to proofread and/or spellcheck your post, it's rather hard to read it like this.

Comment: I have edited the question and added a viewmodel and template binding code. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using if statements, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nwbxexeu/3/

```
div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: messages">
        <!-- ko if: $data.received == true -->
            <li class="left clearfix">
                <!-- Received HTML here -->
            </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: $data.received == true -->
            <li class="right clearfix">
                <!-- Sent HTML here -->
            </li>    
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

In my fiddle I'm not using the template binding. I don't think it adds anything in the fiddle itself, because there's no obvious reason why you'd need to reuse the template elsewhere? However, you might like to use the template bindings in your app, in which case you'll need to attach it to the li element.